# Reading millions of files (in a certain order) and putting them into one big file --- fast

Tags: bash

In my bash script I have the following (for concreteness I preserve the original names;
sometimes people ask about the background etc., and then the original names make more sense):

```
 tail -n +2 Data | while read count phi npa; do
   cat Instances/$phi >> $nF
 done
```

That is, the first line of file Data is skipped, and then all lines, which are of
the form "r c p n", are read, and the content of files Instances/p is appended
to file $nF (in the order given by Data).

In typical examples, Data has millions of lines. So perhaps I should write a
C++ application for that. However I wondered whether somebody knew a faster
solution just using bash?

Comment: you have 1 cat process per file, maybe you want to group these..

Comment: Is there an easy way of doing this grouping? The direction of the above question is in learning perhaps some general trick about bash, however when it gets more complicated, then I likely prefer to write a little C++ program (which would have just a few lines in this case).

Comment: I'd use xargs for something like this. Example incoming in 3, 2, 1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use `cut` instead of your while loop, but you could re-introduce that if it provides some utility to you. The loop would have to output the `phy` variable once per iteration.

```
tail -n +2 Data | cut -d' ' -f 2 | xargs -I{} cat Instances/{} >> $nF
```

This reduces the number of `cat` invocations to as few as possible, which should improve efficiency. I also believe that using `cut` here will improve things further.

Comment: Thanks, I'm evaluating it on my example case, which will take a bit: we have 1365418 lines in Data, and the time-command yields for the original approach (as given in my question) real 54m15.805s, user 12m25.520s, sys 20m58.947s.

Comment: @Oliver Kullmann: I eagerly await your report on any improvement. Certainly I do not know any way to improve this script further. If it's still not performant I would recommend rewriting in another language, ultimately in C if performance in e.g. Perl is not sufficient either.

Comment: for testing purposes you might want to trucate that Data file

Comment: if you use C, copy with `sendfile`.

Comment: rewriting this in another language will not make it faster, because most time is spent reading/writing data.

Comment: Would a solution using the same code as the original with a recommendation to switch to solid state disks technically count as faster solution using bash?

Comment: Sorry that it took so long, but wanted to use the original data ("real-world" example): time yields real 35m49.454s, user 1m46.211s,
sys 5m44.939s, so yes, it is faster! I will now write the C++ program, to see what could be gained, and I post the results. (Going to different hardware doesn't help here, since it's part of an open-source platform which might run under very different circumstances).

Comment: @Oliver Kullmann: You might want to repeat both versions a couple of times and take the latter run as your measure. Filesystem caching would make a lot of difference in runtime.

Comment: I have written now a C++ program, which should be as efficient as possible. Time-command now yields real 16m57.551s, user 0m16.674s, sys 0m56.396s, with very little variation (repeated twice). So 54m for the original code, 34m for the improved bash-version, and 17m for the C++ code. I will repeat the above time-measurements, and if the results turn out to be different, I'll comment here.